# What is the recommended way to build an R package to interface to another application?

Tags: r, rjava

I want to build an R package that interfaces with external piece of software (written in Java). I know this can be done by including the .jar files with the R package and using `rJava` to interact with the other software (similar to how `rWeka` works).

However, the total size of the external application is fairly large and would not fit inside the size limit on R packages hosted on CRAN (which is about 10mb I think)

I have had a look at the R package for `h2o`, and this (i think) does not distribute the .jar file with the package, but connect to the internet and downloads it after installing the r package.

Does anybody have an advice on how to implement this, or any suggestion on a better alternative approach? I want to avoid the user having to install a separate piece of software himself to get the package to work.